# minus lives when collide with enemy not working pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, sprite

I am making a pacman style game in pygame using python and i am trying to make it so that when the `player` collides with an enemy sprite (`monster`) the score gets reduced by 1. The code for the monster and player are below and also the code i have tried to minus the score. Any help would be appreciated. I can post the whole game code if this will help.

The code i have tried to minus the player lives when colliding with a monster is below.

```
for monster in group:
    if player.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
        player.lives -= 1
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Is there an error? Does `lives` change? Where have you placed your new code?

Comment: @SanjayManohar I have just updated my question with the whole code so you can see where i am maybe going wrong. It brings the error that self is not defined in the livestext.

Comment: OK. since you have defined `lives` inside `player`, you should use `player.lives` when you create `livestext`

Comment: Thats updates fine now thank you! The only problem i have now is that the lives is minus by one every time the player moves, could you suggest where to but the collision code in, so that the lives is only minus when the player touches a monster? @sanjaymanohar

Comment: Yes, you have included `player` in the sprite group `group` (when you created the group at the start). In your `for monster in group` loop, you should check to ensure not `monster==group`. `player` always intersects `player`!

Comment: sorry I meant `monster is not player`

Comment: So what would the code be in the for monster in group?  @sanjaymanohar

Comment: `for monster in group:
            if player.rect.colliderect(monster.rect) and monster is not player:
                player.lives -= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you only create `livestext` at the beginning. The should be  re-created each time you print it on the screen.
You seem to be drawing the text right at the end, after the game (why then?). So move the `livestext=...` line to before the `blit`. The lives may well be doing what you want, but perhaps you can't see it?

Also, I'd recommend making `lives` an instance member:

Do `self.lives=5` in the `__init__`

and use `self.lives` instead of `lives` every time it occurs.

Comment: i've just done this but in the livestext it says 'self is not defined'